# Comma vs Semicolon separated csv file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, keyerror

I have the code that  turns some data into a csv file.

```
with open(Result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

When I use this option an open the Result file, the columns are not separated inside Excel.

Not good because I can’t analyze the data.

However, when I read the **Result.csv** file using pandas and  call a column I get the following bellow. Works fine.

```
            Count
0               0
1               0
2               0
3               1
4               0
...           ...
25257           6
```

Now comes the question.

**Do you know that you can add a delimiter inside you code sothe columns are separated by Semicolon ?**

**Answer: Yes**

I have updated the code into this

```
with open('OPDATA_6nrCounter.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
  #  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
```

**Results**

When I open the csv file, it is separated into column, so it is good.

However when I go to read a specific column using pandas I get the following.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Numbers'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I just one to output a csv file that is separated into column but then when I want to read it using pandas and perform other tasks using python to not get these KeyError problems.

Comment: because pandas is assuming a comma delimiter, you must pass the necessary argument to use a semi-colon delimiter

Comment: Set your excel to use a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, is it standard for pandas to take comma as delimiter ?  How would I go about passing the necessary arguments to use a semi-colon ?

Comment: Pandas by default considers 'comma' as delimiter; to change the delimiter, y
ou can use `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',sep=';')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you. Should I delete this questions since there others then ?

Comment: @be1995 no, people may find this question and be re-directed to an answer